# Getting correct version of the package python-django

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dpkg, django

I have `python-django` package installed on `Ubuntu 14.04`. However the version numbers I get with `dpkg -s` and `django-admin --version` does not match.

```
$ dpkg -s python-django | grep Version
Version: 1.6.1-2ubuntu0.11

$ django-admin --version
1.9

$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
```

I want to understand why that's the case. Because I have another Ubuntu and it also has `python-django` package on it and version numbers match.

```
$ dpkg -s python-django | grep Version
Version: 1.7.6-1ubuntu2.3

$ django-admin --version
1.7.6

$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
```

In a nutshell, my question is:

Is is normal to have different  outputs for `dpkg -s` and `django-admin --version` , which one is the correct version?

And, if it is not normal, how can I fix it?

**Edit: output of `command -v django-admin` on Trusty machine**

```
$ command -v django-admin
/usr/local/bin/django-admin
```

**Edit: output of `/usr/bin/django-admin --version` on Trusty machine**

```
$ /usr/bin/django-admin --version
1.9
```

**Edit: output of `apt-cache policy python-django` on Trusty machine**

```
$ apt-cache policy python-django
python-django:
  Installed: 1.6.1-2ubuntu0.11
  Candidate: 1.6.1-2ubuntu0.11
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.1-2ubuntu0.11 0
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.6.1-2 0
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You probably used 'pip' to install and used a version ;)

Comment: Actually, I used `sudo apt-get install python-django`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `command -v django-admin` on your Trusty machine.

Comment: @A.B. It is added.

Comment: You HAVE installed a parallel django version in `/usr/local`. Therefore the difference in the version.

Comment: `/usr/bin/django-admin --version` gives you the correct version.

Comment: I am not sure , as i added to the question it also gives the output `1.9`

Comment: Reinstall `python-django-common` as shown in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, in Trusty the package is python-django. Answer edited.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy python-django`

Comment: @A.B. It is added

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal, if you have installed an additional version without the package manager as in your case.

The path `/usr/local/bin` has a higher priority as the path `/usr/bin`. For that reason, the command

```
django-admin --version
```

shows another version than

```
dpkg -s python-django | grep Version
```

To force the usage of the version 1.6 you have to use the absolute path

```
/usr/bin/django-admin --version
```

and because I do not know what else you have adapted

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-django
```

Comment: I run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-django` but  everything is still the same.